# Jmeter redirection challenges

Tags: testing, redirect, jmeter

## JMeter URL redirection challenges from 302 to 200 status code

I'm trying to perform URL HTTP connection authentication with JMETER and facing challenges on redirection URL with JMeter from 302 to 200 status code within the organization environment. The office environment using windows authentication NTLM2 methods.

However I’m facing URL redirection blockage when I tried to navigate through an internal website as it stops when it reaches 302 status code and failed to navigate further to status code 200 through JMeter but when I display the same URL with chrome browser, it able to successfully display the web with status code 200 using chrome browser.

## How does the URL Authentication work?

1. at 1st the given URL which includes end-user parameters were entered to display the web messages.[shows HTTP status code 302]
2. The URL then redirects to another portal login URL to acknowledge the authentication.[shows HTTP status code 302]

### Problem/Issue:-

- The URL only successfully performing the 1st 2 options but it failed to perform the final redirection to have status code 200
- At the moment the HTTP result in Jmeter through "View Result Tree" and "View Result Table" is both showing status code 302
  [image]

### Limitation

- I couldnt install any external chrome pluggin due to the security restriction within the given operating system environment
- proxy has been included. in both "HTTP default Advance" option and "HTTP Advance" option with the relavent user proxy details, id and password

### Additional Details

- The website were build part of the liferay framework using java spring.

  - We notice through jmeter logs viewer that the "Pooling HTTP Connection Manager" being shut down as well.
  - I've included the log viewer from the JMETER in here

### Challenges

- I'm not sure what further configuration i should do to allow the 3rd redirection to be happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), change "Mechanism" to `BASIC_DIGEST` and provide your domain and Windows credentials there

[image]

This way JMeter will be able to build a proper [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header and you will be able to proceed to your application

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)